# How could we show that the abelian group has $\text{ rank}=0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ the elliptic curve $Y^2=X^3+p^2X$ with $p \equiv 5 \pmod 8$. Show that the abelian group $E(\mathbb{Q})$ has $\text{rank}=0$.

Could you give me a hint how we could do this?

It is known that if $E|_{\mathbb{Q}} Y^2=X^3+aX+b \ \ (a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, D(f) \neq 0)$ then:

$$E(\mathbb{Q})=\{ (\alpha, \beta) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} | \beta^2=\alpha^3+a \alpha+ \beta \} \cup \{ [0,1,0]\}$$

**EDIT**: $p$ is a prime.

Comment: We would like to help you, but we first should have a correct statement. What exactly is assumed on $p$ ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde That is the exact statement.

Comment: It is obviously wrong, unfortunately. Take $p=69,77$ etc. Where did you find this "exact statement" ?

Comment: Our prof gave the exercises to us...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general. For $p=-3$ we have $p\equiv 5\bmod 8$, but the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+9x$ has rank $1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Also, for positive $p$ this need not be true. Take $p=69$. Then $p\equiv 5 \bmod 8$ and the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+4761x$ has rank $2$. So we need an additional assumption on $p$. A
possible reference for such assumptions is  Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", Chapter X, Section 6, "The curve $y^2=x^3+Dx$".

*Edit*: For primes $p$ the question has been asked already on MO and on this site in $2012$, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112053/elliptic-curves-in-form-y2-x3p2x-where-p-is-prime-with-rank-0) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234590/elliptic-curves-with-form-y2-x3p2x).
However, there seems to be no obvious condition, except the ones in Silverman's book. 
Perhaps we should ask your professor about the solution.

Comment: Did you look at section $6$ in Silverman ? Where did you find this statement ?

Comment: Dietrich We also assume that $p$ is a prime. How could we show it then?

Comment: Indeed the professor gave it to us.. What is the rank of the curve for example for $p=5$ ?

Comment: The curve $y^2=x^3+25x$ has rank zero.

Comment: Could you maybe take a look at this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131121/determine-if-e-mathbbq-is-finite-or-infinite